# Cauchy and convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

A sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is called *Cauchy sequence* if for any $\varepsilon>0$ exists $N$ such that $n,m\geqslant N$ implies that $d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon$.

I know that Cauchy sequence not necessarily convergent. But if we look at the definition of Cauchy sequence and take $m=N$ we got that for any $\varepsilon>0$ exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies that $d(x_n,x_N)<\varepsilon$.

And we got the definition of convergent sequence. What's the problem?

Can anyone explain this? Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: The $N$ depends on $\delta.$

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: @Pacman I'm sorry. The $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$ (I always use $\delta$ instead of $\varepsilon$).

Comment: In the semi-open interval $]o, 1]$ you have {$\frac {1}{n}; n\in\mathbb N$}   is Cauchy but it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

A converget sequence has a limit $L$. The definition says:

> $(x_n)$ converges to $L$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist some $N$
>   such that $d(x_n,L)<\epsilon$ for any $n\ge N$.

Note that the limit $L$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ or that $N$. But in the difinition of Cauchy sequences, the inequality $d(x_n,x_N)<\epsilon$ that you have correctly deduced depends on $N$, and $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.